# zend gdata api showing white screen :(

Tags: php, zend-gdata

I am using byethost for my project..
I am trying to install zend gdata on the  server..
I copied all the file to server to "root/ladert/Zend/library"

I tried running the zend installation checker.. but it gives white screen.. NO output( even in view source)

So I tried error show on by runnning php script with "ini_set('display_errors', 'on');" .....since I don  have php ini access I tried that.

But still all what I get is white screen..

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried to run any gdata demo scripts? They may provide errors

Comment: Turning on `display_errors` is only one step.  Please also run use `error_reporting(-1)` to actually turn on the actual errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kavisiegel yes I tried that.. 
@charles thanks..

I finally found that the problem is with my hosting provider... They'll hopefully fix it soon... :)